# Angularjs how to run loader before send request in module?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have module in Angularjs. In this model, before render page, I need to receive some user data **Wallet.getUserWallet();**

```
var app = angular.module('Order', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);

app.config(['routerProvider', function($routerProvider){

    $routerProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'static/js/application/view/main.html',
        controller: 'Main',
        resolve: {
            data: function(Wallet) {
                return Wallet.getUserWallet();
            }
        }
    });
}]);
```

How I can run my loader, before I get userWallet? I have Loader in my directives.

```
<div loader="{{Main.showLoader}}"></div>
```

Comment: could use routeChange events

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you check out [ngBusy](https://github.com/cgross/angular-busy) and [angular-promise-tracker](https://github.com/ajoslin/angular-promise-tracker)

Demo [here](http://cgross.github.io/angular-busy/demo/)